# Programmatically added block doesn't appear in block admin page

Tags: 8, blocks

First of all, this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/199781/17632), as I can't see my block even though I click Place Block.

Below is my block class. To the best of my knowledge, it should appear in the list, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? There is another block class, and that can be discovered.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\tcmb\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'Tcmb Currency' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "tcmb_currency_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("Tcmb: currency"),
 *  category = @Translation("Tcmb")
 * )
 */

/**
 * Display TCMB currencies as a block.
 */
class TcmbCurrencyBlock extends BlockBase {
```

Comment: Can you provide the folder path and the name of the file you put this code in? Your issue may be here. Make sure you're [following this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9fO2.png)

Comment: DRUPAL_ROOT/modules/custom/tcmb/src/Plugin/Block/TcmbCurrencyBlock.php

Comment: So far looks good. Do you have a [public function build() {](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-blocks/create-a-custom-block) ? Did you clear the cache? **Is the tcmb module enabled?** Are you sure you're looking at the correct site? If you're not developing locally, did you make sure your file changes uploaded to the server?

Comment: All of them are yes, but one thing caught my eye. When I open my own file and webform's block class in vim, webform's @Block annotation is blue, whereas mine is green. Could that mean something?

Comment: That was because @Block and the following ( had a space in between, and I fixed that, followed by `drush cr` and still no.

Comment: Create **HelloBlock.php** and [copy & paste this code](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-blocks/create-a-custom-block) change the namespace to `namespace Drupal\tcmb\Plugin\Block;` and don't change anything else. See if you can place this Hello World Block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92639/discussion-between-kartagis-and-no-sssweat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was me creating a document block above the class, creating an interference between the class and annotation. Another lesson learned the hard way.